# difference between perl version

Tags: perl

In perl 5.8.8 I use next construction:

```
Package Common;

BEGIN
{
    require Exporter;
    use vars qw( @EXPORT );
    @EXPORT=qw( test )
}

sub test {
   my ( $self ) = shift
}

1;
```

```
Package My;
use Common;
sub test1 {
  print $self -> test();
}

1;
```

It works. But in perl 5.10.0 it does not work. Why?

Comment: -1 "Does not work" is a not valid question. At a minimum, specify (verbatim) what error messages come up.

Comment: When asking questions like this, it's really helpful if you tell us a) what you were trying to do and b) what unexpected behaviour you saw. Just saying that something "does not work" is no use at all.

Comment: Suggest adding "use strict;" and "use warnings;" to all code. Without them, Perl often looks like everything is fine when it totally isn't

Answer (score 2):

First of all, USUW ( `use strict; use warnings;` ).

And when you do that, you'll see that `$self` is not defined in the scope of (what should be) `package My;` or `My::test1`. Also `Package` is obviously treated as a [bareword](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Barewords) without strict 'subs', which does not mean the same thing as `package` with a lowercase 'p'.

I'm dubious that this works in 5.8. But I no longer have any sub-5.12 environments to check.